# C# background app that needs to auto-start after reboot not working on Windows 7 (even after adding manifest)

Tags: c#, background-process

**UPDATE 6/29/18 4:15pm PT:**

The error message has changed. I've tried signing the .exe and that hasn't helped. I've tried uiAccess="false" and uiAccess="true" and neither seems to work. I've googled "How do I force my .NET application to run as administrator?" and that it says that adding a manifest should work for both Win 7 and Win 10.

---

We have an app written in C# that runs in the background and needs to auto-start after a reboot. So we had some trouble getting it to restart and I learned that we needed to add a manifest file to elevate it's privileges to Admin , so I did that and it started working on windows 10, but now it doesn't work on Windows 7. I enabled the Win 7 section of the manifest (see below) but still get this error when trying to run the app:

[image]

Here's the manifest section enabling the app for Win 7:
[image]

Anyone have any idea what could be wrong? If we remove the manifest the app starts fine on Win 7, but doesn't auto-restart in Admin mode (which is required).

Comment: Well, it worked, you correctly got a message to tell you that this is not possible.  The UAC prompt cannot be displayed at login time.  You'll have to consider a service or a scheduled task.

Comment: But it works on Win10. And the elevate is supposed to happen automatically given the manifest. Why would it work on Win 10 and not Win 7?